# Haskell: how to make attempted retrieval of not-yet-received messages from state unrepresentable?

Tags: haskell, types, state

I'm writing a Haskell application that talks to a remote end over the network, and accumulates messages received into a state object in a State monad:

```
newtype ProtoS r s a = CProtoS {
    getProtoS :: S.StateT s (ReaderT r (ExceptT ProtocolError IO)) a
} deriving (Monad, Functor, Applicative, MonadError ProtocolError, MonadIO)
```

I have modelled the state object as a data type containing a number of `Maybe *msg*` objects. Here's an example for the server end:

```
data ServerProtocolState = ServerProtocolState {
    spsChannelOpenParameters    ::  Maybe ClientVersion
    ,spsOpenResponse            ::  Maybe OpenResponse
    ,spsOpenFinalize            ::  Maybe OpenFinalize
    ,spsLastPayment             ::  Maybe Payment
} deriving Show
```

The messages are received in the order they appear in the ServerProtocolState type. So first the state is empty (all `Nothing`s), then a ClientVersion is received, and now the state contains a `Just clientVersion` with all the rest Nothing, then the next message is received and the state is `(Just clientVersion) (Just openResponse) Nothing Nothing`, and so on.

How do I make attempted retrieval of an object from this state, before it has been received, unrepresentable? Or is there a better way to model it than this?

Comment: maybe you could add a phantom type => `data ServerProtocolState a = ...` and a can be an empty data type that indicates the state. Could also be that multiparamtypeclasses are helpful

Comment: @epsilonhalbe that's the idea I had as well. but I'm unsure how to implement it. I think I need a `transition` function, which takes a `ProtoStage t => ProtoS r (ServerProtcolState t)` plus a message received, and transitions from one "stage" to the next. then pass eg. `ProtoS r (ServerProtcolState HelloStage)` along with the message that must be available in `OpenStage`, and it would return `ProtoS r (ServerProtcolState OpenStage)`. but I'm not sure this would even work (I'm somewhat new to Haskell), so that's why I'm asking the question. I tried implementing it but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can you briefly outline which protocol states are valid when? It will really help in writing up a proposed solution without making too many assumptions.

Comment: @runeks What you are described seems like it would be possible to model in the Haskell type system, but like Daniel Wagner said, you would need to provide more details about the protocol states.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've updated the question with an explanation. Also, writing the explanation, I realized that this data type can also represent invalid states, which isn't exactly desirable. This makes me further doubt it's the right way to model it. `ServerProtocolState Nothing (Just openResponse) Nothing Nothing` would be an invalid state, for example (the ClientVersion message hasn't been stored).

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing indexed monads are for. They go beyond the Haskell `Monad` class, but can be represented. McBride has done a lot of fancy work with them, but for simple enough situations, Atkey's simpler version will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a hierarchy of types that each contain the information from previous levels. So, for example:

```
data Level0 = Level0
data Level1 = Level1 Level0 ClientVersion
data Level2 = Level2 Level1 OpenResponse
data Level3 = Level3 Level2 OpenFinalize
data Level4 = Level4 Level3 Payment
```

Then you would have your monad be parameterized by what level you're at, and you would want to add some "promotion" functions. For example:

```
receiveVersion :: MonadIO m => ReaderT Level1 m a -> ReaderT Level0 m a
receiveVersion action = do
    version <- liftIO ({- ... -})
    ReaderT $ \level0 -> runReaderT action (Level1 level0 version)
```

You can of course do all kinds of type-level hackery and typeclass hackery to give all the promotion functions the same name and specify the information hierarchy more abstractly.